# Standard deviation of number of terms in a sum

Tags: standard-deviation, sum

If some random variables are drawn from a normal distribution `N(m, s)` with `m > 0` until the sum of the draws exceeds some target, `M`, what is the standard deviation of the number of draws needed? An approximation in the limit `M >> m` is fine if the exact answer is messy.

Comment: May help you find useful information: this question relates to stopping times in random walks.